# Taking a backup of Pentaho

Tags: backup, pentaho

How to take a backup of Pentaho BA server related files? What are the necessary DBs needed to take a backup of?
Answer is provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary steps are mentioned below.

 1) Login to the Pentaho installed server with a user who has necessary permission to OS related files. 

 2) Stop BA server. 

 3) Take a complete database backup of the quartz, hibernate, and jackrabbit databases. If you’re using Postgresql, use the command‐line tool `pg_dump` in the postgresql bin folder. You will need to authenticate as the main database user for each database (`jcr_user` for jackrabbit, `hibuser` for hibernate, and `pentaho_user` for quartz). For example (from the command‐line) – for the jackrabbit database:

`“C:\Program Files\pentaho\postgresql\bin\pg_dump” –U jcr_user jackrabbit > %TEMP%\jackrabbit.dmp` (Windows) 
  
 Or 
 
   `postgresql/bin/pg_dump –U jcr_user jackrabbit > /tmp/jackrabbit.dmp (*nix)` 

 4) Take a backup of full bi-server directory

**NB** : You can also use the import-export utility to backup content only

Follow the link below to Upload and Download from the BA Repository, Using the import-export utility Download the content to backup.

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fadmin_guide%2Ftask_import_export_repository.html