# Pentaho Biserver-ce 4.8: Export / Import Datasources

Tags: import, export, datasource, pentaho

We've created some datasources (and customized their measures and categories) and some reports on DEV environment and we want to "deploy" them on PRODUCTION environment. How could we do it?

Copying the datasources files (*.xmi, *.mondrian) directly to /opt/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/admin/resources/metadata doesn't work.

Copying the report files to pentaho-solutions seems to work (after creating "manually" the datasource).

Comment: Try my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705068/taking-a-backup-of-pentaho

Comment: Thanks but in our case, it's not useful. Adding new datasources in the PRODUCTION envirnoment will be do frequently, it's not viable as diary process.